# What is the purpose of option X in curl?

Tags: curl

Per curl [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html), section 11.2 (given below for reference), if you use the --request / -X option **you can change the method keyword** curl selects, **but you will not modify curl's behavior**.  If -X option doesn't modify curl behavior, what is the purpose of this parameter?

> It should be noted that curl selects which methods to use on its own
>   depending on what action to ask for. -d will do POST, -I will do HEAD
>   and so on. If you use the --request / -X option you can change the
>   method keyword curl selects, but you will not modify curl's behavior.
>   This means that if you for example use -d "data" to do a POST, you can
>   modify the method to a PROPFIND with -X and curl will still think it
>   sends a POST. You can change the normal GET to a POST method by simply
>   adding -X POST in a command line like:
>
> curl -X POST http://example.org/ ... but curl will still think and
>   act as if it sent a GET so it won't send any request body etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity's sake, let's assume we're only talking about HTTP here.

The protocol (HTTP) has certain semantics. Examples:

- Result of `GET` can be cached.
- Data of `PUT` can be cached.
- Server may ignore the body of `GET`.

etc..

curl knows the protocol's semantics and implements it based on the arguments to curl: `-d` implies semantics of `POST`, `-I` implies semantics of `HEAD` etc.

Now, an HTTP requests looks like this:

```
POST /api/v1/hello HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*

hello world!
```

Where the first word in the first line is the HTTP method, `POST` in the above example.

What the documentation is saying is: `-X` allows you to send to the server whatever you want in first word in the first line, but the semantics implemented by the client (curl) is still controlled by the other options to curl and NOT by the first word sent to the server.

Do note that the server doesn't know what options you gave curl, so the semantics implemented by the server WILL be based by the first word in the first line.